# Sending a value from JQuery to AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, alpine.js

I want to pass the values from my JQuery to the AlpineJS (Component) so that I can execute the modal. I want to implement a multiple selection delete function (bulk delete). Here's my code.

This is my `recycle.php` file where jquery, alpine and some php are included.

```
<div x-data="{
modalDeleteBulk: false,
password:'',
userId: 0,
seletedUserIds: [],
openModalDeleteBulk(){
        this.password = '';
        this.modalDeleteBulk = true;
    },
    handleModalDeleteBulk(id){
        this.seletedUserIds = id;
        this.openModalDeleteBulk();
    },
    handleDeleteBulk(){
        if(this.password === ''){
            this.errors.push('Password input is empty!');
            return;
        }

        postData('api/<?php if($_GET['view'] == 'users'){echo("users.php");} elseif($_GET['view'] == 'survey'){echo("surveys.php");} elseif($_GET['accounts']){echo("users.php");}?>?action=deleteThesePerm', {
            password:this.password,
            recycle_id:this.seletedUserIds,
        }).then((data) => {
            if(data.status === 201){
                alert('Deleted successfully');
            } else {
                alert('There is an error. It is either you put an invalid password or internal error.');
            }
    });
        this.modalDeleteBulk = false;
    }
}">
```

the modal inside it

```
<section x-show="modalDeleteBulk" x-cloak>
        <div class="h-full w-full bg-gray-600 top-0 left-0 right-0 bg-opacity-75 absolute flex flex-row justify-center items-center z-50">
            <div class="bg-white rounded shadow">
                <div class="border-b p-3 flex justify-between items-center bg-green-600 text-white font-semibold">
                    <h4>Confirmation</h4>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" @click="modalDelete = false" class="h-6 w-6 cursor-pointer" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="p-3 max-full">
                    <form action="">

                        <div class="text-xs text-red-400" x-show="errors.length > 0">
                            <template x-for="error in errors">
                                <li x-text="error"></li>
                            </template>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-2 mb-3" x-show="userId === 0">
                            <label for="">Enter admin password to confirm.</label>
                            <input type="password" x-model="password" class="bg-gray-50 outline-none border px-3 py-2 rounded w-96 hover:border-2 hover:border-blue-300 hover:bg-white">
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex justify-end">
                            <button type="button" @click="handleDeleteBulk()" class="bg-red-600 text-white py-2 px-5 rounded flex items-center gap-x-1 hover:bg-red-400">
                                <span>Delete</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is my table where I can select multiple checkboxes.

```
<table id="table_id" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%"><button type="button" id="delete-selected" class="bg-red-500 text-sm text-white px-2 py-1 rounded hover:bg-red-400 flex items-center gap-x-1" disabled>Delete Selected</button>
            <br>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select All<br><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-body">
                    <?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="select-user" data-user-id="<?= $user['id'] ?>"></td>
                            <td><?= $user['lastname'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $user['firstname'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $user['username'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= getRole($user['role_id']) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

my JQuery, i want to call the `handleModalDeleteBulk()` here (e.g. `handleModalDeleteBuld(selectedUserIds);`

```
$('#select-all').click(function() {
    $('.select-user').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $('#delete-selected').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});

// Handle the selected users checkbox
$('.select-user').click(function() {
    var allChecked = $('.select-user:checked').length === $('.select-user').length;
    $('#select-all').prop('checked', allChecked);
    $('#delete-selected').prop('disabled', !allChecked);
});

// Handle the delete selected button
$('#delete-selected').click(function() {
    var selectedUserIds = [];
    $('.select-user:checked').each(function() {
    selectedUserIds.push($(this).data('user-id'));
    });

    if (selectedUserIds.length > 0) {
        // the code will be here
    }
});
```

It's been hours thinking about how can I achieve this. Thank you in advance for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove jQuery completely and use Alpine.js data model for each part of your code, it will be much cleaner and easier to understand. Here I provide a minimal Alpine.js example that fulfill the same purpose as your jQuery code.

First we have a new `userIds` array that holds all user IDs. We can have [multiple `x-init` directives](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init#standalone-x-init), so we put one to each checkbox via `x-init="userIds.push(1)"` (or with PHP: `x-init="userIds.push(<?= $user['id'] ?>)"`) to fill the array. We will use this array to check some `disabled` conditions on the buttons.

Next we have an [`x-model="selectedUserIds"` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model) on each checkbox, so when an user clicks on a checkbox its value will be automatically added/removed to `selectedUserIds` array.

The rest is just some utility buttons with `:disabled` logic. The bulk delete modal will now work since we have already filled the `seletedUserIds` array.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{
  modalDeleteBulk: false,
  userIds: [],
  selectedUserIds: [],
}">
  <div x-text="`All userIDs: ${userIds}`"></div>
  <div x-text="`Selected userIDs: ${selectedUserIds}`"></div>
  <div x-text="`Is modal opened? ${modalDeleteBulk}`"></div>
  <div>
    <button @click="selectedUserIds = userIds" :disabled="selectedUserIds.length == userIds.length">Select all</button>
    <button @click="selectedUserIds = []" :disabled="selectedUserIds.length == 0">Deselect all</button>
    <button @click="modalDeleteBulk = true" :disabled="selectedUserIds.length == 0">Delete selected</button>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" x-model="selectedUserIds" value="1" x-init="userIds.push(1)"> User #1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" x-model="selectedUserIds" value="2" x-init="userIds.push(2)"> User #2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" x-model="selectedUserIds" value="3" x-init="userIds.push(3)"> User #3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```